# Creating a file hierarchy based on data across two worksheets

Tags: file, vba, excel, hierarchy

I have a workbook that contains 2 sheets.

- **Sheet1**: a list of Sub assemblies (many parts put together to make one part of a bigger machine)
- **Sheet2**: a list of all the parts that make up the sub assemblies

I need to create a file hierarchy based on this data.

Cell A2 of Sheet1 holds the overall machine part name, which is the first level (this is not a problem). The second level of the file system is created by all of the remaining data in col A of the sheet (every time there is new data in col B, we then create a second level folder using the number in col A and the name in col B)

The problem I have is with the final level of the structure. I need to create third level folders in second level folders, based on the data in Sheet2.

I will give an example.

> In Sheet1 the part name is "Infeed Section", the "Infeed Section" is made
>   up of 6 parts from Sheet2 that are part 1, part 2, part 3, part 4,
>   part 5 and part 6.
>
> These parts all start with the same 6 numbers which are 2414-21xx-xxx
>
> I need to create subfolders for each of the parts with the number
>   2414-21 to go into the folder for Infeed Section. I will then need to
>   do similar checks on the remaining data to do the same.

Now the overall big problem is that this is an automated program and will need to work universally on data that may not start 2414 and could be 5200 or any combination of numbers.

SOLVED: I was going the wrong way about this, I have found a much simpler way to achieve my overall goal. I will however leave this here if it is deemed acceptable to do so in case anyone has a similar problem they are searching for answers with. If it is closed I will happily accept that also

Comment: Appreciate the edit, looks a lot clearer now, was writing it in a rush to get it out there as soon as possible